# How to read in a mathematical function from a function in R?

Tags: r

What I want to do is read in a function from the user within a function.

Okay, so first of all I looked at the documentation of R, and I ascertain that readline is good for reading in a string of text, and scan is good for reading in logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw, and lists. That seems like a lot like it should be able to do what I want it do. But it can't read in a function. That's my point.

So I thought I'd start with a function: fx = x^2 + 3 
If I integrate this function with respect to x from a lower limit of x = 1 to an upper limit of x = 5, then the area under this curve is 53 + (1 / 3) = ~ 53.33333333

This is how you integrate the function in R.

```
    > fx <- function(x){x^2 + 3}

    > integrate(fx, lower = 1, upper = 5)
    53.33333 with absolute error < 5.9e-13

    # To extract the value without the error, it's ...

    > integrate(fx, lower = 1, upper = 5)$value
     [1] 53.33333
```

I want to compute the average value of any function using a function with the following formula for the average value of a curve form calculus:

average value = [1 / (b - a)]  * <sub>a</sub><sup>b</sup>∫f(x)dx

Basically, that's the area under the curve from "a" to "b" over the range "a" to "b" integrated with respect to x. So I want to create a function which can compute the average value of any function within user specified ranges.

```
So the average value of the above function is 53.33333 / (5 - 1) = 13.33333
```

First of all, I checked if my "fx" is.logical, is.integer, is everything that the scan function can received, and it's all not. It's all false.

This is my code that I think should solve the problem, except it's not working.

```
   average_value_function <- function()
{
    print("I will compute the average value of curve over a user defined range")
    print("Give me a function")
    print("Example type: 5*x + 3")

    user_function = readline() # scan() doesn't work, either.  

    fx <- function(x)
    {
        user_function
    }

    print("Give me the lower bound")
    lower_bound <- scan(file = "", what = numeric())

    print("Give me the upper bound")
    upper_bound <- scan(file = "", what = numeric())

    area = integrate(fx, lower = lower_bound, upper = upper_bound)$value

    interval = upper_bound - lower_bound

    average_value = area / interval

    print(average_value)
}
```

When I try the code my average_value_function skips over the fx function scan statement and gives me the following error message:

```
> average_value_function()
[1] "I will compute the average value of curve over a user defined range"
[1] "Give me a function"
[1] "Example type: 5*x + 3"
[1] "Give me the lower bound"
1: 1
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Give me the upper bound"
1: 5
2: 
Read 1 item

Error in integrate(fx, lower = lower_bound, upper = upper_bound) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
Called from: integrate(fx, lower = lower_bound, upper = upper_bound)
Browse[1]>
```

This function works beautifully if I reduce the reduce the machine learning potential of this function considerably by setting the function to x^2 + 3 and not accepting standard input.

```
average_value_function <- function()
    {
        print("I will compute the average value of curve over a user defined range")
        print("Give me a function")
        print("Example type: 5*x + 3")

        fx <- function(x)
        {
            x^2 + 3 # main change 
        }

        print("Give me the lower bound")
        lower_bound <- scan(file = "", what = numeric())

        print("Give me the upper bound")
        upper_bound <- scan(file = "", what = numeric())

        area = integrate(fx, lower = lower_bound, upper = upper_bound)$value

        interval = upper_bound - lower_bound

        average_value = area / interval

        print(average_value)
    }
```

So here it is working with reduced machine learning potential.

```
> average_value_function()
[1] "I will compute the average value of curve over a user defined range"
[1] "Give me a function"
[1] "Example type: 5*x + 3"
[1] "Give me the lower bound"
1: 1
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Give me the upper bound"
1: 5
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 13.33333
```

TL;DR

Basically, the issue is that a scan and readline statement can't be accepted within a function even its scanned into a variable and then passed in or passed into the function directly, and also the issue is that scan and readline are incompatible with function structure types.

I would like my code to work so that a user can input any function and any integration bounds and get the average value out of that such that a user could input literally any function: x^2 + 3, log(x), 2*x + 5, 1 / x, x^(8) + 3, and get the integration function to work on the appropriate bounds and user defined function to collect the appropriate average value.

Comment: You need eval(parse()) if you want to follow this path. Note that users can do bad things if you do this. There is no security whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are saying that doing that causes me to lose a lot of security? How exactly does accepting a function from the user cause such a drop in security? It's just a function.

Comment: It says "object x not found".

Comment: I feel like fx <- function(){ readline(expression())} 
should work but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are getting a characters string from the user. That strings needs to be parsed in order to evaluate it. And you have no control over the user input.

Comment: If it's a character string, then in the function: x^2 + 3,
then it would be split to three parts "x^2", "+", and "3", right?